# Have large Buddhist reference library to donate

Tags: reference-request, tibetan-buddhism, books

Dear Friends in the Dharma,

Over the years i have accumulated a large Buddhist reference library along with other associated topics.
The collection together is far more valuable and useful than the individual volumes would be separately.
Does anyone know of a stable situation that such a collection may be donated to?

Sincerely, Mr Norman

Answer (score 2):

### Internet Archive

> If you will donate books we need for our library, then the Internet
> Archive might pay for shipping– please contact us.
>
> Start here!
> https://help.archive.org/help/how-do-i-make-a-physical-donation-to-the-internet-archive/

Once a Public Domain book has been scanned and is on the Internet, it is available to Billions of people. Even blind people can "read" a book using the text-to-speach feature. A scanned book can also be automatically translated to almost any language.

Answer (score 0):

I don't.

Perhaps the Buddhist studies department of a university, or a university professor, might accept them or be able to advise.

My mum wanted to donate my dad's collection (of Roman history books) to an Oxford college. It took her a while to find one, but she did eventually, it was a newer college (for graduate students) -- with a new campus, and a library that wasn't already full.

Comment: Thinking more a small center or perhaps scholar.  Not entire collection is library quality although it is diverse and top-rate reference quality.  Most universities and larger centers subscribe to on-line reference services that seem to make collections such as mine obsolete or unnecessary.  Thank you for encouragement  

Answer (score -1):

Recently, I donated some Suttas to a secluded monastery that has a relatively large amount of residents compared to its seclusion and thus no individual access to internet. However, smaller monasteries & Buddhist libraries  were not interested in my Suttas because they can now be read online.

Comment: Indeed subscriptions to various types of networks that librarians utilize have made books almost obsolete. 
Scholars tend to utilize these online research options while most people tend not to read books or pursue reading.  
Research collections in the past have always been difficult to accumulate and more difficult to keep together and donate.  Things seem even more difficult now